# No value given for one or more required parameters in asp.net in C# vs2010

Tags: c#, asp.net

same values sequence as in database but give error No value given for one or more required parameters in asp.net in C# vs2010 kindly guide me

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //string url = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=& Server.MapPath(northWind.mdb.accdb)";
        //string url = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=& northWind.mdb.accdb;";
        string url = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Z:/WebSite2/northWind.mdb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(url);
        conn.Open();
        string query = "INSERT INTO Customer Values(fname.Text,lname.Text,phone.Text,mail.Text,password.Text,fname.Text);";
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.AcceptChanges();
        adp.Fill(ds,"Customer");
        adp.Update(ds);
        DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables["Customer"]);
        DataGrid dgv = new DataGrid();
        dgv.DataSource = dv;
       // dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dgv.DataBind();
        Response.Redirect("main.aspxs");
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception Exp)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Error Found in Main page process");
        throw Exp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with your query

```
 string query = "INSERT INTO Customer Values(fname.Text,lname.Text,phone.Text,mail.Text,password.Text,fname.Text);";
```

It should be using string concatenation instead of string in double quotes. it should be

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Customer Values('"+fname.Text+"','"+lname.Text+"','"+phone.Text.....
```

the full query will be

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Customer 
Values('"+fname.Text+"','"+lname.Text+"','"+phone.Text+"','"+mail.Text+"','"+password.Text+"','"+fname.Text+"');";
```

### Edit 1

Aslo you should be using Parametrized query to get rid of Sql injection. Some examples

1. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Comment: error fname  in fname.Text does not exist in the current context

Comment: What you have written there any idea what is `fname`

Comment: fname is id of textbox where user give his first name

Answer (score 0):

look you have not passed values to insert into database.
Your Insert Statement Must be like this :

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Customer Values('"+fname.Text+"','"+lname.Text+"','"+phone.Text+"','"+mail.Text+"','"+password.Text+"','"+fname.Text+"')";
```

Your Code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
    //string url = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=& Server.MapPath(northWind.mdb.accdb)";
    //string url = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=& northWind.mdb.accdb;";
    string url = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Z:/WebSite2/northWind.mdb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(url);
    conn.Open();
   string query = "INSERT INTO Customer Values('"+fname.Text+"','"+lname.Text+"','"+phone.Text+"','"+mail.Text+"','"+password.Text+"','"+fname.Text+"')";

    OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.AcceptChanges();
    adp.Fill(ds,"Customer");
    adp.Update(ds);
    DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables["Customer"]);
    DataGrid dgv = new DataGrid();
    dgv.DataSource = dv;
   // dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    dgv.DataBind();
    Response.Redirect("main.aspxs");
    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception Exp)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Error Found in Main page process");
    throw Exp;
}
```

}

Comment: how do you come to know the exact column names?

Comment: i just make consideration that he passes 'fname.Text' as value then fname may be his column name

Comment: error fname  in fname.Text does not exist in the current context and all other like this

Comment: look just tell me your aspx control names through which you passing values to query

Answer (score 0):

Instead on using dataAdapter to fire insert on table, have you tried doing it using command? In that case code will be like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //string url = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=& Server.MapPath(northWind.mdb.accdb)";
        //string url = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=& northWind.mdb.accdb;";
        string url = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Z:/WebSite2/northWind.mdb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(url);
        conn.Open();

        // this must be your query, it should be build up using concat operator (+)

        string query = "INSERT INTO Customer Values('"+fname.Text+"','"+lname.Text+"','"+phone.Text+"','"+mail.Text+"','"+password.Text+"','"+fname.Text+"')";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,conn);
        var res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Here res will tell you records inserted or not, -1 for successful insertion  
        cmd = null;

        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds,"Customer");
        DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables["Customer"]);
        DataGrid dgv = new DataGrid();
        dgv.DataSource = dv;
       // dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dgv.DataBind();
        Response.Redirect("main.aspxs");
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception Exp)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Error Found in Main page process");
        throw Exp;
    }
}
```